# What .Net controls are available for diagram markup?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, controls

We need to mark up diagrams of body parts to indicate the location and extent of injuries.

For example, to shade an area of the body to mark a burn, or a diagram of a hand with an amputated finger.

What 3rd party controls are available that would be suitable for embedding into a .Net application?

Comment: What kinf of .Net app? Asp.net, WinForms?

Comment: Sorry, meant to put WinForms in the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own by drawing colored lines, circles and shaded elipses on a pre-loaded image of a body outline using mouse dragging events. Took a couple of days, but the users find it suits their needs perfectly. Even managed to get a bit fancy and throw in an undo, and marker labels for them.

Their previous version (VB6) actually drew on the background image which was then saved as a bitmap blob, but my routine saves the markings as simple objects overlayed on any image that can be selected for relabelling or deleting, and saved in text as a structure of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try DevExpress